# How to secure Nikon Cameras open WIFI?

Tags: privacy, access-control, wireless

In Nikon digital cameras which support WiFi like D5300 you can browse and transfer the photos by enabling the WiFi and connecting to the camera SSID which is open and do and there is no option to protect it by any level of authentication or encryption and run the WMU application on your mobile , I am wondering how we can limit the access to the camera in this case?

Comment: Really interesting question, disappointing to see the only option is WPS (from the the poster below) as it's insecure. There's a lot of very insecure cameras out there leaking photographs if WPS is not on by default.

Comment: I think even WPS is not very secure and it is vulnerable to brute force attack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have much options there, it's only uses WPS for WiFi security. So you have to enable or select push-button WPS.

[image]